# Kendo Grid Edit InLine model.Field(o => o.Property).Editable() depending on other Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an entity Document:

```
public class Document : EntityBase
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SourceLink{ get; set; }
    public bool IsFile { get; set; }
}
```

and I am using the Kendo Grid InLine Edit Mode.
And now I want to make the Property `string SourceLink` editable, depending on `bool IsFile`.
That means the `SourceLink` should be editable if `IsFile==false`.

_documentsView.cshtml:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
    .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(o => o.ID);
                model.Field(o => o.SourceLink).DefaultValue("");
                model.Field(o => o.Description).DefaultValue("");

                if (model.Field(o => o.IsFile) == true) { 
                    model.Field(o => o.SourceLink).Editable(false)
                }
                else
                {
                    model.Field(o => o.SourceLink).Editable(true)
                }
             }
    )
    //.Create(update => update.Action("GridEditingInlineCreate", "Document", new { area = "" }))
    //.Read(...)
    //...
)
```

Is there a possibility to get this if statement in the `.Model` statement working?
Or is it generally possible to use such a depending Editable feature?
Maybe in another way?

Comment: I think I will bypass the requirement with two Grids. One with elements where IsFile==true, the second one with elements where IsFile==false. So I can handle the Editable(true/false) option separately.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you decided to go a different direction. You might consider using a template for that column that either disables the field or writes it as a label based on the `IsFile`. Otherwise, I think you're stuck with your current workaround since editability is set on the datasource and not at a row level.

One other consideration though - you might be able to use a shared editor template to write out the label instead of an Editor...